# Acceleration vs. time from acceleration vs. distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, acceleration

Let's say we have two point bodies, each of mass of 1 unit, 1 unit apart. If we exclude any external forces, gravity starts slowly pulling them towards each other. At some point, the bodies are together. We need to calculate after how much time this happens.

It is possible to solve this by using equations for two orbiting bodies for an ellipse with b=0 (the answer is 1/4 of the full orbital period). Now I'm trying to find a way to solve this using calculus.

A thing that we can write straight away is an acceleration vs. distance traveled graph for one of the bodies:
$$a(x) = a(x(t)) = \frac{G}{(1-2x)^{2}}$$
The problem is that velocity and acceleration go towards infinity when close together as the bodies are points without dimensions.

I tried to calculate average acceleration by first calculating area under the graph:
$$ \int_{0}^{0.5}a(x)dx = \int_{0}^{0.5}\frac{G}{(1-2x)^{2}}dx$$
However, this integral does not converge. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A better method would be to use conservation of energy to find relation between velocity and displacement.

Comment: Or use $a =v \frac{dv}{dx}$

Comment: Velocity and acceleration go to infinity as x goes to $0$, but time does not. The time contributed by the high velocity part of the trajectory is small. You might calculate the time from $0.5$ to $x_0$ and take the limit as $x_0$ goes to $0$

Comment: You're calculating the average acceleration by integrating over distance, which is not what you want.

This goes back to the old problem: if you walk 1 mile out at 5 mph and then 1 mile back at 3 mph, what is the average speed?  It's not 4 mph! it takes you 12 minutes to walk out and 20 minutes to walk back, so that's 32 minutes to do 2 miles which is only 3.75 mph. Less than 4 because you spent longer walking at the slower speed.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Will post the solving steps soon.

Comment: I don't understand the (1 - 2x).  Where is the origin of your coordinate system?

Comment: Your acceleration is positive. Doing anti-gravity?   If the masses start one unit apart, why integrate from zero?

Comment: The coordinate system has origin at the center of one of the bodies at the beginning of motion, and points towards the other body. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: OK, but I'm thinking the math would be simpler and less confusing if you put the origin at the center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

According to Abhinav's suggestion, $a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$. Rearranging the terms and integrating both sides gives us $$\int a dx=\int vdv=\frac{v^{2}}{2}$$ Inserting $a(x)=\frac{G}{(1-2x)^{2}}dx$ gives us
$$ v=\sqrt{G(\frac{2x}{1-2x})} $$
Inserting this into $dx=vdt$ gives us $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1-2x}}}=\sqrt{G}dt$$
Integrating the left side in Wolfram Alpha gives us [this awful function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20dx%2F%28sqrt%282x%2F%281-2x%29%29%29). [Limit of this function while x approaches 0.5 from the left](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2FSqrt%5Bx%2F%281%20-%202%20x%29%5D%20%2B%20%28Sqrt%5Bx%5D%20ArcSin%5BSqrt%5B2%5D%20Sqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%29%2F%28Sqrt%5B2%5D%20Sqrt%5B1%20-%202%20x%5D%20Sqrt%5Bx%2F%281%20-%202%20x%29%5D%29%29%2FSqrt%5B2%5D%20for%20x%3D0.5) is approximately $0.785398$.

Assuming SI base units and $G=6.67*10^{-11} (m^{3} s^{-2}kg^{-1})$:
$$t(x=0.5) =\frac{0.785398}{\sqrt{G}} \approx 96167 \ seconds \approx 27 \ h$$
which is the correct answer.

Comment: Please correct if I made any incorrect steps.

Comment: What are the limits on your integrals?

Comment: Hm, not sure if I understand, do there have to be limits as these are antiderivatives? We are looking for values within the domain between x=0 and x=0.5.

Comment: As long as all of your variables start from zero, you should be alright within a domain.  I set up a 100 step numeric simulation that agrees wth your result.  In using the formula for a 2 body orbital period, I found that the drop time corresponds with (½) the thin elliptical orbit period. (Each mass comes in to the CM and then goes back out.)